# Converting existing project to Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have an existing project based on the code found at: https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086 . As an exercise in learning TensorFlow, I am trying to convert this code to use TF, however, much of the API documentation seems to expect prior knowledge of various terms not present in the code I am porting. I'm assuming I would use SimpleRNN or some subclass of RNN.

What would a basic TensorFlow version of this code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some spare time and a lot of fiddling, I came up with something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, initializers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adagrad

SCALE = 100.0

def makeXVector(ix):
    x = np.zeros((vocab_size, ))
    x[ix] = 1.0
    return x

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    print('Reading and tokenising input.txt')
    data = f.read()

print('Collecting chars')
chars = list(set(data))
data_size, vocab_size = len(data), len(chars)
char_to_ix = { tok:i for i,tok in enumerate(chars) }
ix_to_char = { i:tok for i,tok in enumerate(chars) }

# hyperparameters
hidden_size = 300 # size of hidden layer of neurons
seq_length = 25 # number of steps to unroll the RNN for
learning_rate = 1e-1

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(
    layers.SimpleRNN(
      hidden_size,
      activation='tanh',
      use_bias=True,
      stateful=True,
      bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),

      # (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)
      batch_input_shape=np.array((1, 1, vocab_size))
    )
)

model.add(
    layers.Dense(
      vocab_size,
      activation='softmax',
      use_bias=True,
      bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(),
    )
)

model.compile(
    optimizer=Adagrad(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy'
)

n, p = 0, 0
smooth_loss = -np.log(1.0/vocab_size)*seq_length # loss at iteration 0

def sample(model, seed_ix, n):
    x = makeXVector(seed_ix)
    ixes = []
    for t in range(n):
      p = np.array(model.predict(np.array([[x.ravel()]]))).ravel()

      # Select a random character based on the probability
      ix = np.random.choice(list(range(vocab_size)), p=p)
      x = makeXVector(ix)
      ixes.append(ix)

    return ixes

print('data has {:d} characters, {:d} unique.'.format(data_size, vocab_size))

try:
    while True:
      # prepare inputs (we're sweeping from left to right in steps seq_length long)
      if p+seq_length+1 >= len(data) or n == 0: 
        p = 0 # go from start of data
      inputs = [char_to_ix[tok] for tok in data[p:p+seq_length]]
      targets = [char_to_ix[tok] for tok in data[p+1:p+seq_length+1]]

      # sample from the model now and then
      if n % 100 == 0:
        sample_ix = sample(model, inputs[0], 200)
        txt = ' '.join((ix_to_char[ix][0] for ix in sample_ix))
        print('----\n{}\n----'.format(txt))

      hist = model.fit(
        np.array([[inp] for inp in map(makeXVector, inputs)]),
        np.array([targ for targ in map(makeXVector, targets)]),
        verbose=0
      )

      loss = hist.history['loss'][-1]

      smooth_loss = smooth_loss * 0.999 + loss * 0.001
      if n % 100 == 0: print('iter {:d}, loss: {:f}'.format(n, smooth_loss)) # print progress

      p += seq_length # move data pointer
      n += 1 # iteration counter 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```